# Create new HKQuantityType

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, watchos

I've read in some pages that you can add custom samples to `HealthKit` in order to have another measurements saved.

In my case, I want to add accelerometer data from the apple watch to `HealthKit`.

This is my code

```
func saveSample(data:Double, date:NSDate ) {
    let dataType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.init(rawValue: "acc"))
    let dataQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.init(from: "m/s^2"), doubleValue: data)
    let dataSample = HKQuantitySample(type: dataType!, quantity: dataQuantity, start: date as Date, end: date as Date)
    healthKitStore.save(dataSample, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
        if( error != nil ) {
            print("Error saving sample:")
        } else {
            print("Sample saved successfully!")
        }
    })
}
```

I want to add a sample called "acc" (in a normal case one example of this could be "bloodPreasure") with unit "m/s^2".

I get nil on dataType, so then I get this `Error` on `let dataSample = HKQuantitySample(type: dataType!, quantity: dataQuantity, start: date as Date, end: date as Date)` line, because dataType is nil.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any ideas,How to implement this? Thank u all!

Comment: the error is because i get nil in dataType, and I don't know why, maybe I'm doing something wrong when I create it.. I get the error in 'let dataSample = HKQuantitySample(type: dataType!, quantity: dataQuantity, start: date as Date, end: date as Date)' because I entered a nil value as type

Comment: and how do I create new Type?

Comment: yes, that's what i want.. do u know how to create a new one different for the ones provided by ios?

Comment: Ok, thanks in case!

Answer (score 0):

I believe for `HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier:` we need to provide identifier provided by apple like `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyTemperature`. And then only it will return an object of quantityType.

So you are getting nil in `dataType`.

And I believe we can't create new HKQuantityType because health store will have to save it too, and that part is not in our control.